# Will multiple databases be the best way?

Tags: couchdb, multiple-databases

I have a CouchDB scenario which involves:

- A business has multiple (10000's) discrete clients.  I.e data is not shared between clients.
- Each client has a set of <10K documents.
- Clients have a 'life' of about 3 years - after which data can be archived/removed.
- End users will only use one database at a time.

I'm thinking each client would be a separate Couch database. Is having loads of DBs a good pattern?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [couchdb multiple databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503089/couchdb-multiple-databases)